# Huffman Code - Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault, binary-tree, huffman-code

Ok I have tried to make the Hauffman Code by my own and I have a problem when I'm trying to print the corresponding code to each letter with a recursive method.

(By this point I already created a BinaryTree and root is not NULL)
Each node has a value and if it's a leaf it also has a letter, so I begin going down the tree node by node but it seems that in the recursive method the node just forgot who he was or I don't know, I have tried a lot of things. :S

The recursive method is **createCode**(Node* actual, string actualCode);

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_VALUE 256
int frequencies[MAX_VALUE] = {0};

struct Node {
    int value;
    char letter;
    struct Node *Left, *Right;
}*root=NULL, *temp, *left_temp, *right_temp;

struct CompareNode : public std::binary_function<Node*, Node*, bool> {
    bool operator()(const Node* lhs, const Node* rhs) const {
        if (lhs->value == rhs->value)
            return lhs->letter > rhs->letter;
        else
            return lhs->value > rhs->value;
    }
};

void createCode(Node* actual,string actualCode) {
    if (actual->Left == NULL && actual->Right == NULL) {
        cout << "For: " << actual->letter << " is " << actualCode << endl;
    }
    else {
        if (actual->Left) {
            createCode(actual->Left, actualCode + "0");
        }
        if (actual->Right) {
            createCode(actual->Right, actualCode + "1");
        }
    }
}

void createTree() {
    priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, CompareNode> que;

    for (int x = 0; x < MAX_VALUE; x++) {
        if (frequencies[x] > 0) {
            temp = new Node;
            temp->value = frequencies[x];
            temp->letter = char(x);
            que.push(temp);
        }
    }

    while (que.size() > 1) {
        temp = new Node();
        temp->Left = que.top();
        que.pop();
        temp->Right = que.top();
        que.pop();
        temp->value = temp->Left->value + temp->Right->value;
        temp->letter = NULL;
        que.push(temp);
    }

    root = que.top();
    que.pop();
}

void fillArray(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string line;
    const char* ptr;

    ifstream myFile(argv[argc - 1]);
    if (myFile.is_open()) {
        while (myFile.good()) {
            getline(myFile,line);

            if (line.length() != 0) {
                ptr = &line.at(0);

                while (*ptr != '\0')
                    ++frequencies[*ptr++];
            }
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "The file could not be open.";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    fillArray(argc, argv);

    createTree();

    createCode(root, "");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the example tree (I tried to post the image but because I'm new I could't):

[Binary Tree Image](http://f.cl.ly/items/2d423V1X3e2G451h2Z36/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-14%20at%207.31.55%20PM.png)

And here's the output:

```
For: a is 0
For:   is 10
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Please help :(

Comment: Most likely, `actual->Left` or `actual->Right` point to a `Node` that is corrupt or non-existent. You can use tools like `valgrind` to track the problem. (Perhaps you allocate a `Node` and didn't set `Left` and `Right` to NULL?)

Comment: If a node has only one child (which _should_ not happen in a Huffmann tree), `createChild` will crash trying to access the other child as well.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Good catch. The giveaway would be that in that case, the crash would occur in `createCode` and `actual` would be `NULL`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz too bad we don't have the stack trace.

Comment: What am I missing here guys?  Looks like `root` is set to 0 and then used before ever being initialized (and that assignment would result in an error anyway)

Comment: @EdS. not shown in the code: `root` is modified before being walked.

Comment: @JanDvorak: That would be an important piece of info.  I was just going to post an answer describing how this code wouldn't even compile and, if `root` were intended to be a pointer, the cause would be obvious.  The example introduces another possible segfault.

Comment: @EdS. `(By this point I already created a BinaryTree and root is not NULL)`

Comment: @JanDvorak: Right, but as the OP is unable to deduce the cause of the problem I am wary of taking that statement at face value.  Often people *think* they are doing the correct thing, but of course they're not, which is why they came here.  The example should not omit details which may be relevant.  Also, again, that code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @EdS. I can write a "the bug is in your other code" answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak: not sure what that means, but ok.  Point is, don't introduce additional bugs in your example and certainly do not post code which doesn't compile (unless you are asking how to solve a compiler error of course).

Comment: Ok I edit the code and now that is the complete code. I already check "if each child exist then proceed to check it" but the error is the same.

Comment: `int frequencies[MAX_VALUE] = {0};` IIUC this will produce an array with its first element equal to zero. Try `int frequencies[MAX_VALUE]()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialise the `Left` and `Right` pointers to `NULL` when creating the `Node`s you push into the queue:

```
if (frequencies[x] > 0) {
    temp = new Node;
    temp->Left = NULL;
    temp->Right = NULL;
    temp->value = frequencies[x];
    temp->letter = char(x);
    que.push(temp);
}
```

Without explicit initialisation, these pointers have indeterminate values, and often not `NULL`, thus in `createCode` you are dereferencing invalid pointers.